# Добавить кнопку со счетчиком в ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, customview

Мой toolBar:

[image: ToolBar]

Над корзинкой нужно добавить количество товаров в ней:

[image: ToolBar cо счтчиком]

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Стандартного и простого способа не существует. Смотрите разные костыли типа как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28442840/3212712)

Comment: Есть готовая библиотека [Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger), которая позволяет прицепить бэйдж к любому View - если не хочется заморачиваться, лучший вариант.